# Insert Statement into same table causes inconsistent bottlenecking

Tags: insert, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently having an issue with a particular SQL Server table used within a database, I cannot run an insert statement on this table when the records I'm selecting are coming from itself.

Here's the statement:

```
insert into [Custom Work] ([Description], [Price], [Cost], [Labour Cost], [Made In Material], [Bought Out Material], [Weight], [Machine Shop], [Axles], [Stakes/Bunks], [Beam], [GNK], [Parts], [Line], [Step 1], [Step 2], [Blast], [Paint], [Finish], [Finish - GNK], [Final Assembly], [Shipping], [Eng Hours], [Option Date])
   select 
       [Description], [Price], [Cost], [Labour Cost], 
       [Made In Material], [Bought Out Material], [Weight], 
       [Machine Shop], [Axles], [Stakes/Bunks], [Beam], 
       [GNK], [Parts], [Line], [Step 1], [Step 2], 
       [Blast], [Paint], [Finish], [Finish - GNK], 
       [Final Assembly], [Shipping], [Eng Hours], [Option Date] 
   from 
       [Custom Work]
   where 
       Description = 'custom stuff'
       and Quote# = 123456
```

When I insert records from another table (say when we're adding a standard option as custom work), it works great like it always has! But when I insert records from itself, it will work here and there but then times out (when run from Access) or goes on forever (if run from SSMS).

This started happening after I made some table structure changes, however I made the same structure changes to the standard options table we have... so, if I can't insert records into itself I shouldn't be able to insert records from another table! :|

I've also ran a trace to help diagnose this issue, but it doesn't provide much for leads...

There's no triggers set against this table, select/update statements also work fine (from all the experimentation I've done)! I've even restarted SQL Server (running SQL Server 2008 R2) after hours (which usually fixes this issue for me), but it didn't this time.

I'm guessing corrupt table properties (foreign/primary keys, constraints, indexes, statistics, etc.) perhaps? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT:** Would a mere drop and create statement on this table fix this issue? If not, drop and recreating all the table properties?

Comment: It's been a couple months... Just wondering if anyone knows what else might cause this as it still occurs every now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this via chat with Yugz, this issue was persisting with this specific table because my front end Acccess db still had locked records on this table (which caused my lock-free insert statement to spin and hinder SQL performance). Also, I haven't been rebuilding my SQL database indexes on a regular basis.

So, for anyone else having this issue, make sure you front-end applications selecting data isn't locking down records and rebuild your indexes! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using WITH (NOLOCK)?

```
insert into [Custom Work] ([Description], [Price], [Cost], [Labour Cost], [Made In Material], [Bought Out Material], [Weight], [Machine Shop], [Axles], [Stakes/Bunks], [Beam], [GNK], [Parts], [Line], [Step 1], [Step 2], [Blast], [Paint], [Finish], [Finish - GNK], [Final Assembly], [Shipping], [Eng Hours], [Option Date])
   select 
       [Description], [Price], [Cost], [Labour Cost], 
       [Made In Material], [Bought Out Material], [Weight], 
       [Machine Shop], [Axles], [Stakes/Bunks], [Beam], 
       [GNK], [Parts], [Line], [Step 1], [Step 2], 
       [Blast], [Paint], [Finish], [Finish - GNK], 
       [Final Assembly], [Shipping], [Eng Hours], [Option Date] 
   from 
       [Custom Work] WITH (NOLOCK)
   where 
       Description = 'custom stuff'
       and Quote# = 123456
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried your suggestion but ended up with the same results... it didn't work the first time, worked when I left it alone for a while, then didn't work the third time :/.

Comment: Would you know what else might be causing this? I've dropped and recreated this table several times (due to table structure changes and such) and this issues is still persistent.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the data you want to insert into a Temp table and then select from the temp table into your [Custom Work] table

Comment: Try to remove spaces and special characters like "/"," "- from your column names you rather use an underscore "_" or keep it as 1 word

Comment: I tried the temp to SQL method, my make table query works fine but as soon as I try to go from my temp to the live SQL table, it spins... same as going from the original insert to the live SQL table. Thing is, I've had this SQL table for about 2 1/2 years... why would it start doing this a couple months ago? Plus I have "/" and " " special characters throughout my SQL databases... why would it affect just this one table?

Comment: If you'd like to see the SQL table structure, I'll send you the create statement for it.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... this is a weird one. Do you have any idea how many records are being inserted into the table ?
Also check that your TempDB files have enough space when the query is executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78920/discussion-between-jcbws-and-yugz).